# get file name of directory and subdirectory using CMD

Tags: cmd, directory

I am making an inventory for which I need to copy all file names in an excel sheet. Right now I am using cmd command "**dir /s /w /p > file.txt**" for every folder. Problem is that when I get the txt files, file names are in same line, and I have to select them and copy paste in Excel sheet. I need a command that gives me all files names should come in new line so that I can easily copy all file names at once and paste them.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting file names in the same line because you use the `/w` (wide) option, which does exactly this, check /w parameter here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir

To solve your problem simple don't use the `/w` parameter. You can see the result below

[image]

Comment: I tried it but I dont need time and date. Is there any way I can remove time and date from it ?

Comment: you can import the output to excel then remove the date and time colums in Excel